# Ruby Rack Heroku: Serving Static Files

Tags: ruby, heroku, rack

I have followed the Heroku guide on deploying static files using Ruby Rack (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby), but I was unable to access any HTML file in `\public` apart from `index.html`. Namely, `localhost:9292/test.html` still maps to `index.html`. (All my style and js files serve correctly).

Below is my `config.ru` file. I know what's wrong, but not sure about a valid solution?

```
use Rack::Static,    :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],   :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|   [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)   ] }
```

Answer (score 3):

For your `config.ru` file, try:

```
use Rack::Static,
    :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
    :root => "public"

run Rack::File.new("public")
```

You could also replace the last line with `run Rack::Directory.new("public")` which would serve up all your files, but would give a file browser like interface if someone went to the url of a directory (like the root directory)

Answer (score 0):

I have no Ruby experience and I found this boilerplate project helpful when trying to deploy a static website to Heroku:

[heroku-static-site](https://github.com/jamiew/heroku-static-site)

Particularly, make sure you also have `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` files besides the `config.ru`.

Author's project structure hosts everything in the root directory but you can easily move everything to `public/` and correct the `config.ru` as @looby suggested.