# Ruby Rack Heroku : Unable to access multiple URLs

Tags: ruby, heroku, static, rack

I have followed the Heroku guide on deploying static files using Ruby Rack (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby),
However I am unable to access any HTML file in \public apart from index.html (every URL resolves to the home page)
The config.ru file :

```
use Rack::Static,
:urls => ["/bootstrap", "/css", "/fonts", "/images", "/js", "/font-awesome"],
:root => "public"
run lambda { |env|
[
 200,
{
  'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
  'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
},
File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
]
}
```

I have checked the following posts : 
[Ruby Rack Heroku: Serving Static Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189252/ruby-rack-heroku-serving-static-files)
[How to setup URLs for static site with Ruby Rack on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206289/how-to-setup-urls-for-static-site-with-ruby-rack-on-heroku)
Still I am unable to go beyond the index.html page.
While I change the config.ru as shown below ... I get application error

```
use Rack::Static, 
:urls => ["/bootstrap", "/css", "/fonts", "/images", "/js", "/font-awesome"],
:root => "public"

map "/" do
 run lambda { |env|
 [ 
   200, 
  {
   'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
   'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
  },
  File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
 ]
}
 end

 map "/about" do
  run lambda { |env|
  [
     200, 
   {
    'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
    'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
   },
   File.open('public/about/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
 end
```

Is there a way to map multiple URLs? I have 5-6 pages in my index.html, but unable to access.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple controller that just renders these pages. May be easier than trying to bypass the MVC. Let me know if you need help with this :)

#### Update -----

**Example**

Controller:

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  def index
     render "public/index"
  end

  def about
    render "public/about/index"
  end
end
```

Then place your html files in the views folder in the sub-directories specified in the controller.

Also don't forget to add these methods to your routes.rb file in the config directory.